# Shared Excel workbook fine on local machine, freezes on shared drive

Tags: excel, shared

This workbook has macros, although does not have a Workbook_Open sub, or any other code that automatically runs on opening the file.

The macros are to manage updating data on one sheet, but using a UserForm to manage user input and perform data validation. One operation causes moving a row from one sheet to another sheet.

I developed this for someone else. It works fine on my machine, and it works fine on his machine. When he copies it to a network drive, he says it freezes as soon as he tries to do anything. I do not have network drive available (yet) to reproduce this.

I cannot think of anything that *should* cause behavior to be different on a network drive, as long as the drive is responsive.

I know there are some limitations for what can be done in a shared workbook, but to my knowledge none of them apply here.

Are there any known problems with macro-enabled shared workbooks on network drives? Troubleshooting advice?

Answer (score 0):

Through extensive debugging I discovered the problem. I was running it without being shared, and he was running it as shared. When I shared it, I started seeing the same problem. I isolated the problem to a Sort command. It was sorting a column by specifying A:A.  When I changed it to restrict it to the rows used, there was no problem. My suspicion is that in a Shared workbook, the code was attempting to sort all 1,048,576 rows instead of just the rows within UsedRange. I do not know why there would be any difference in how Sort works for a Shared workbook, but this solved it.